# Parsing multiple commands for a simple shell program

Tags: c

I am trying to write a simple shell program that would be able to parse multiple commands separated by a semicolon. For example ls;pwd would function as two separate commands. I have figured out for single commands but am not able to parse multiple commands. Since windows does not allow fork() how do I parse the multiple commands. I can check for semicolon using strchr() but do not know how to build a function that would parse multiple commands. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

char line[MAX];
char *newline;
char *input[50];
char  newinput[MAX];
char *exitString="exit";
char *open ="ls";
char *executepwd ="pwd";
int i=0;

while (1){

getcwd(current_directory, sizeof(current_directory));

printf("$->");

fgets(line,MAX,stdin);

if (strchr(line,';')){

//I do not know how to parse multiple commands without fork()   

    printf("There are a lot of commands");

}


else{
//I could parse single commands but not multiple

if (strstr(input[0],exitString)){
    printf("Exiting the program\n");
    exit(0);
    printf("\n");

}

else if 
    (strstr(input[0],open)){
    ls();
    printf("\n");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged it, so ditch C and use C++. `std::getline` and `std::stringstream` turn most of this problem into a couple lines of code. A `std::map` mapping `std::string`s to `std::function`s does most of the work for handling the commands once you get them.

Answer (score 1):

Use getopt to parse and get input parameters to your program

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html